# Odd looking dropdown when out of hover

Tags: jquery, sass, dropdown

So I was messing around with some dropdowns, when I got to this very annoying glitch. You can see it in action here: https://codepen.io/iAmGuus/pen/NaWWjB
So when you hover over the About section, you can see the dropdown works just fine until unhover. I believe it has something to do with the margin & padding on the ul.nav-dropdown.
This is the SCSS:

```
& ul.nav-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    list-style-dropdown: none;
    // padding-left: 0;
    margin: .5rem 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #c55050;
    border-top: 1px solid #c55050;

  }

  & li.dropdown-item {
    background-color: #c55050;
    // display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50%;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
  }
```

The remaining code can be found in my codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by instead of doing my own animation I just used the jQuery slideUp & slideDown functions.

```
$(this).slideUp();
$(this).slideDown();
```